# Reset toggle on click of another button

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I reset ongoing toggle?

Below is the code that I am using and at very last comment I have defined what I need.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {
    var funcs = [func1, func2];
    this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
    this.click(function() {
      var data = $(this).data();
      var tc = data.toggleclicked;
      $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
      data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
    });
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));

function showTakeNotes() {
  // some functions will here while SHOWING the notes
}

function hideTakeNotes() {
  // some functions will here while HIDING the notes
}

// Capturing the toggleClick event of '.btn-show-hide-take-slide-note'
$('.btn-show-hide-notes').clickToggle(function() {
  showTakeNotes();
}, function() {
  hideTakeNotes();
});

// there is another close button within the Notes widow to close the window
$(".btn-close-take-notes").clickToggle(function() {
  hideTakeNotes();
}, function() {
  // HERE I LIKE TO RUN RESET EVENT THAT'S ALREADY RECORDED WHILE SHOWING THE NOTES WINDOW .btn-show-hide-notes
});
```

Comment: What is reset event?

Comment: @Satpal if I click `.btn-show-hide-notes` button for first time then `showTakeNotes()` function will be called and if i click the same button again then `hideTakeNotes()` function will be called. There is another button `.btn-close-take-notes` from which I like to reset the event that's already captured while clicking `.btn-show-hide-notes`. By resetting click event of `.btn-show-hide-notes` button, even for the second time `showTakeNotes()` function should be called rather `hideTakeNotes()` function.

Comment: Which function should be called is controlled by `toggleclicked`, you can try with `$('.btn-show-hide-notes').data('toggleclicked', 0);`

Comment: @Satpal thanks, that works. Please add it as answer rather comment, I will mark it as accepted answer :)

Comment: Done, Added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which function to be controlled by `toggleclicked` data. If you want to reset it to call `showTakeNotes` function. you can use

```
 $('.btn-show-hide-notes').data('toggleclicked', 0);
```